# How can I adjust the Snowflake function to get date with error that it cannot parse?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert numbers in this format `1180106` to dates.

I've been able to run the following query to get a YYYYMMDD format until today:

```
TO_DATE(1900 + LEFT(A.ODT_ENTERED_DATE, 3) || SUBSTR(A.ODT_ENTERED_DATE, 4, 4), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

The inner query builds a number like this: `2018.000000106`
But then the TO_DATE function cannot create a date from it. I'm expecting `20180106`

Instead I get the following error:

```
Can't parse '2018.000000106' as date with format 'YYYYMMDD'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just run:

```sql
select 1900 + LEFT(A.ODT_ENTERED_DATE, 3)
```

this returns the result as a `varchar` where the result returned is: `2018.00000`

Cast to number in either of the following ways should give you the expected result :

```sql
select TO_DATE(1900 + TO_NUMBER(LEFT(1180106, 3))|| SUBSTR(1180106, 4, 4), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

or

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE((1900 + (LEFT(1180106, 3))) :: number || SUBSTR(1180106, 4, 4), 'YYYYMMDD')
```